# INVALID_ARGUMENT: Failed to parse headers when adding a ServerInterceptor

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I have a Java gRPC service which is working in production already. I am trying to add a ServerInterceptor to add tracing and logging context to it, but when I add the interceptor, the tests fail with the following error.

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Failed to parse headers.

    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:271)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:252)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:165)
```

I have tried removing the custom code and just adding barebones, but still the same, so I am convinced that it's not my tracing/logging code, but the way I am creating the interceptor. Any idea what can be improved here?

Here's the interceptor I have created (the bare bones, without the custom code)

```java
public class ObservableServerInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
      ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall,
      Metadata metadata,
      ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> serverCallHandler) {

    return serverCallHandler.startCall(serverCall, metadata);
  }
}
```

And here's how I am adding it

```java
final GrpcServer grpcServer = environment.resolve(GrpcServer.class);
grpcServer.intercept(new ObservableServerInterceptor());
```

Edit:
I forgot to add the bit where I am trying to get values from the Metadata and when I comment it out, everything works. Here's the code in my intereceptor for the same

```java
final Map<String, String> contextFromRequest = new HashMap<>();
    metadata.keys().stream()
        .forEach(
            key -> {
              Metadata.Key<String> metadataKey =
                  Metadata.Key.of(key, Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
              contextFromRequest.put(key, metadata.get(metadataKey));
            });
```

So may be it's the way I am extracting the values?

Comment: "Failed to parse headers" does not appear to be a grpc-java string. So that's either your own code or some library you didn't mention you are using. What library defines the `GrpcServer` and `environment` classes? When parsing metadata, keys that end with "-bin" are binary headers and can't be used with ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER.

Comment: @EricAnderson You're right! That was actually the parsing issue of the binary headers. I added a condition to skip those headers and it started working properly.